# How can one export the wireshark gui commands as a tshark commandline program?

Tags: wireshark, pcap, tcpdump, tshark

If you repeat the same routines again and again it would be practical to export them as an equivalent tshark commandline program.

Comment: Could you please clarify your question" : what do you call "wireshark commands" ??? Setup a display filters? Action such as selecting a TCP packet and then doing a "follow TCP dialog"? ... ?

Comment: @jbm commands = ui interactions

Comment: @jbm     "Setup a display filters? Action such as selecting a TCP packet and then doing a "follow TCP dialog"?"   Exactly Actions that transform the data you are inspecting. For example howto export the ui actions and settings described in https://www.imperialviolet.org/2012/06/25/wireshark.html as tshark shellscript? Is there a wireshark log file? Hopefully this answers your question!

Comment: OK. Just to be nitpicking: "actions that transform the data you are inspecting". These actions do not **transform** the data you are inspecting in any way, they are transforming _the way they are displayed_, which is quite different (the whole original data is still there).

Comment: Please do have a look at my edit, it's pretty significant! Basically change from "no" to "yes".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the clarification on your question.

<strike>And then my answer is:</strike>

**No**, there is no way.
`tshark` is not scriptable / does not have a macro language or such.

What you could do through is pipe its output to a script/program of your own that would to the job, but that's a whole different project.

Very important EDIT:

I was **wrong**, there is a way of "scripting" wireshark / tshark.

(I've heard of it, but never used it myself, so it did not pop in my head immediately, sorry)

Both `wireshark` an `tshark` do have scripting capabilities using the `lua` language. Not sure this may suit your needs but have a look at:

https://wiki.wireshark.org/Lua

https://wiki.wireshark.org/Lua/Examples

As I understand it, most of the time it's intended to be used as dissector prototyping, but it can go beyond that.

Hope this help.